# How to automatically log out of Chrome daily

Tags: google-chrome

I need to remember my password. In order to remember my password, I need to be forced to type it frequently. Unfortunately Chrome has a habit of keeping me logged in for an extended period of time.

**How do I set up Chrome to force me to type my password once a day** (bot not more often, which would be annoying)?

When I try to search for help online all I can find is information about how to stay signed in -- exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: why not use a [password manager](https://www.google.hu/search?q=password+manager&oq=password+mana&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5709j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)??

Comment: My password manager has a password.

Comment: That would be that only one password you need to remember, I've started using it a year ago, and now I've 100+ passwords in it.

Comment: Assume, for the sake of argument, I really want to remember my Chrome password.

Comment: Write it down and stick it your monitor or put it in your wallet.

Comment: Stick the password on the monitor!?!? Seriously!? I would -1 that comment 10 times if I could.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this on some college based machines, you will require cookies to be deleted on logoff or logon,

Open up notepad:

> REM - Remove User Profile
>
> RMDIR "C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\" /S /Q
>
> Exit

Then save file as whatever.bat (ensure that filetype .txt is changed to all file types)

You can then place a shortcut to it in your startup folder.

Note this will delete all locally saved settings for your chrome browser every time you turn on your PC and log into it. You would need to click "link account" or whatever every time you login to pull your cloud based saved shortcuts etc.

Note2 you will remain logged in until you turn off your PC or log out of your PC. Locking your PC and unlocking the PC will not run the script.

Comment: The script should probably be called "Delete user profile" instead of "Remove Chrome cookies." It's not elegant, but will

Comment: @Appleoddity I suppose, I only had it named like that as that is the location of where chrome cookies are stored, to-may-toes / to-mah-toes.

Comment: Also, if anyone wanted to do this on a multiuser device for all users, I believe you can use %USERNAME% rather than stating a username ensuring that it is in the all users startup folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use Incognito mode. And at the end of the day, close your browser. Done.

Comment: I want all the features that go with being logged in to Chrome.

Comment: You're not making sense. Please update your question. You mentioned specifically, "Chrome has a habit of keeping me logged in to Google/Gmail account." If your issues is with being signed in to Chrome, that is different. Incognito mode will solve the problem you asked and will behave exactly the same while you are logged in.

Comment: When you're logged into Chrome, what you're logged into is your Google account, which is the same as your Gmail account (if you have one), Google+ account (if you have one), etc. But I've removed the words that seemed to have created confusion.

Comment: I understand your question better now. I'm still not sure why incognito mode doesn't work for you? If the goal is to remember your password, then even if you are signed in to Chrome, if you switch to incognito mode you will have to sign in to gmail and other google services every time.

Comment: Perhaps what Charles is trying to say is that he still wants to have browser history and the other browser features that you lose in incognito mode. And perhaps the answer is that he can’t have it both ways.

Comment: I agree. But again, if the goal is to have to type your password in once a day, and assuming you check your email daily, then run gmail in incognito mode. Everything else is run in a normal mode. I doubt history is important for gmail.